# Trying to use the BeautifulSoup Python module to pull individual elements from table data

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and currently using BeautifulSoup with Python to try and pull some table data. I cannot get the individual elements out of the td. What I have so far is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/region-ALL/tournament-LCS%20Summer%202020/week-ALL/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

td = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'text-center'})

print(td)
```

This does display all of the td that I want to extract but am unable to figure out how to get each individual element out of the td.

Thank you in advanced for the help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: What is missing? the first row and column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/region-ALL/tournament-LCS%20Summer%202020/week-ALL/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

td = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'text-center'})

print(*[text.get_text(strip=True) + '\n' for text in td])
```

Prints:

```
S10
 NA
 14
 35.7%
 0.91
 1744
 -48
 33:19
 11.2
 12.4
 5.5
 7.0
 50.0
 64.3
 2.71
 54.2
 1.00
 57.1
 1.14
```

and so on....

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for this I will give this a try when I get off work today to see it in action!

Answer (score 0):

The following script extracts the data and saves the data to a csv file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get('https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/region-ALL/tournament-LCS%20Summer%202020/week-ALL/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("table", class_="table_list playerslist tablesaw trhover")

columns = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in table.find("thead").find_all("th")]

data = []

table.find("thead").extract()

for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
    data.append([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all("td")])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

```
               Name Season Region Games Win rate   K:D   GPM   GDM Game duration Kills / game Deaths / game Towers killed Towers lost   FB%   FT% DRAPG  DRA% HERPG  HER% DRA@15 TD@15  GD@15 NASHPG NASH%   CSM   DPM  WPM  VWPM  WCPM
0       100 Thieves    S10     NA    14    35.7%  0.91  1744   -48         33:19         11.2          12.4           5.5         7.0  50.0  64.3  2.71  54.2  1.00  57.1   1.14   0.4   -378   0.64  42.9  33.2  1937  3.0  1.19  1.31
1               CLG    S10     NA    14    35.7%  0.81  1705  -120         35:25         10.6          13.2           4.9         7.9  28.6  28.6  1.93  31.5  0.57  28.6   0.64  -0.6  -1297   0.57  30.4  32.6  1826  3.2  1.17  1.37
2            Cloud9    S10     NA    14    78.6%  1.91  1922   302         28:52         15.0           7.9           8.3         3.1  64.3  64.3  3.07  72.5  1.43  71.4   1.29   0.7   2410   1.00  78.6  33.3  1921  3.0  1.10  1.26
3          Dignitas    S10     NA    14    28.6%  0.86  1663  -147         32:44          8.9          10.4           3.9         8.1  42.9  35.7  2.14  41.7  0.57  28.6   0.79  -0.7   -796   0.36  25.0  32.5  1517  3.1  1.28  1.23
4     Evil Geniuses    S10     NA    14    50.0%  0.85  1738    -0         34:09         11.1          13.1           6.5         6.0  64.3  57.1  2.36  48.5  1.00  53.6   1.00   0.5    397   0.50  46.5  32.3  1895  3.2  1.36  1.34
5          FlyQuest    S10     NA    14    57.1%  1.28  1770    65         34:55         13.4          10.4           6.5         5.2  71.4  35.7  2.86  53.4  1.00  50.0   0.79  -0.1     69   0.71  69.2  32.7  1801  3.2  1.16  1.72
6  Golden Guardians    S10     NA    14    50.0%  0.96  1740     6         36:13         10.7          11.1           6.3         6.1  50.0  35.7  3.29  62.8  0.86  42.9   1.43   0.1    711   0.50  43.6  33.7  1944  3.2  1.27  1.53
7         Immortals    S10     NA    14    21.4%  0.54  1609  -246         33:54          7.5          14.0           4.3         7.9  35.7  35.7  2.29  39.9  1.00  53.6   0.79  -0.4  -1509   0.36  25.0  31.4  1734  3.3  1.37  1.47
8       Team Liquid    S10     NA    14    78.6%  1.31  1796   135         35:07         11.4           8.6           7.9         4.4  42.9  64.3  2.36  43.6  0.93  50.0   1.14   0.2    522   1.21  78.6  33.1  1755  3.5  1.27  1.42
9               TSM    S10     NA    14    64.3%  1.12  1768    52         34:20         11.6          10.4           7.2         5.7  50.0  78.6  2.79  51.9  1.21  64.3   0.93   0.1   -129   0.86  57.1  32.6  1729  3.2  1.33  1.33
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response I really appreciate it. At work now, but can't wait to try it when  I am off!